# access windows 10 localhost from mac running parallels 14

Tags: parallels

How can I access the localhost of windows 10 from my mac.

I'm running parallels 14 from my mac.

If I look at my hosts file it looks like this:

```
10.211.55.3     windows-10.shared windows-10 #prl_hostonly shared
```

BUt I cannot curl `windows 10` or `10.211.55.3      windows-10.shared`

Answer (score -2):

1. In configuration / setting of Window Parallels, select tab "Hardware" and look for Network. Make sure source option is selected as Shared Network (Recommended).
2. In Macbook, open System Preferences > Network, you will see IP address. Copy this IP address, you will need it to run as host for your local server.
3. Run local server with the host of the copied IP address. Use the same ip address to access your local server in Window Parallels' browsers.